# How to use macro function for multiple <p> in xml with xPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
I need to extract address, telephone no using xPath from my html page. My 
address is sometimes within one `<p>`, else within two `<p>`. I have 11 
stores.
This is the html tag <p> in my xml. (Just an example)

<div class="info-block-value"> ==$0
   <p>36 rue de la Verrerie 75004 PARIS</p>
   <p>Tél : 0111 222 222</p>
  </div>
<div class="info-block-value"> ==$0
   <p>11 rue des archives</p>
   <p>75004 PARIS</p>
   <p>Tél : 01 11 11 11 11</p>
  </div>

1st shop: P1 =address P2= tel
2nd shop P1= address P2 = tel P3 = fax
3rd shop P1=address line 1 P2 = address line 2 P3= tel
4th : P1 = address P2 = tel
5th : P1= add P2 = tel
Shops 6,7,8,9,11 : P1 = add line 1 P2 = add line 2 ( they have no 
telephone)
10th shop : P1= add line 1 P2= addline 2, P3= tel, P4= space P5 = email

I tried with,
```

> {
>             "name": "store Addr",
>             "key": "Address",
>             "xPath": "(//div[@class='info-block-value']/p)[1] | 
>                      (//div[@class='info-block-value']/p)[2]",
>             "level": 0,
>             "enabled": true,
>             "values": []
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Tel No",
>             "key": "TelephoneNumber",
>             "xPath": "(//div[@class='info-block-value']/p)[2]| 
>                      (//div[@class='info- 
>                      block-value']/p)[3]",
>             "regex": "Tél : ((\d+\s*)+)+",
>             "level": 0,
>             "enabled": true,
>             "values": []
>           }

```
But I'm not getting the correct results. Can someone help me this?

Results:

id name address                               phone 
1  a    36 rue de la Verrerie 75004 PARIS     0111 222 222
2  b    11 rue des archives                   01 11 11 11 11

Expecting results
id name address                               phone 
1  a    36 rue de la Verrerie 75004 PARIS     0111 222 222
2  b    11 rue des archives  75004 PARIS      01 11 11 11 11
```

Comment: What results are you getting? What results do you expect?

Comment: modified the question

Answer (score 0):

You basically need all the `<p>` but the last one for the address, and the last one for the telephone number.

So, get the address with

```
//div[@class="info-block-value"]/p[position() < last()]
```

and similarly, the telephone number is under

```
//div[@class="info-block-value"]/p[last()]
```

Comment: But this isn't give the correct results, still I'm not getting the address who are in two <p>

Comment: Show the code. It works for me in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh).

Comment: What happens when the XPath returns a nodelist, i.e. more than one node?

Comment: What do u mean by more than one node?

Comment: The XPath with `position() < last()` returns two `<p>` elements in the second case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194002/discussion-between-user-and-choroba).